# sent bitcoin and its not in the blockchain and not showing "unconfirmed" to my other wallet

Tags: transactions, blockchain

Last night I transferred $400 btc from purse.io to my paxful.com wallet. and it didn't show in my blockchain record and I didnt received any "unconfirmed" . What happened? is my BTC lost?

paxful address: 3EHttCtQtNU4BZvf5YvjbnDruhd1ubDvBT

purse.io address: 1BM6mMXb4ZHMMSx3JnZnhnTkE5Rh5VNnj9

my tx said by purse : https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/e68ad64dba66c61d316bb628a97d0346f11eaa2a5d86f27233b8b5b2178903c2

Comment: blocktrail url returns 404

Answer (score 0):

Here is the receiving address on blockchain: https://blockchain.info/address/3EHttCtQtNU4BZvf5YvjbnDruhd1ubDvBT. It seems 0.028028 BTC where received.

Comment: it was yesterday. I can only see my past transactions.

Comment: It seems we are looking at a past transaction? Only such transactions can be seen in the blockchain.